# SFMC - Migrating Automations and Journeys from one Business Unit to other Business Unit

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, automation, migration

I have a use case where I have to migrate all the automations and journeys from one business unit to other business unit. Is there any way that I could avoid doing it manually and save time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Deployment Manager for Journeys: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_deployment_manager.htm&type=5

For Automations, you could try SOAP API if you have experience with Marketing Cloud APIs: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/interacting_with_automation_studio_via_the_web_service_soap_api.htm

Otherwise, you would have to re-create them manually.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)